# Firebase dynamic links not opening the react native app

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

In my react native app, the firebase dynamic link is not opening the app.
I have added the intent-filter in AndroidManifest.xml file.

`

```
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
         android:scheme="https"
            android:host="brite.page.link"
            />
    </intent-filter>`
```

also the required changes to setup firebase are also done. but then also i am facing this problem.

I am expecting it to open the app

Comment: any updates on your issue ? I'm having the same...